# Need to save response to a file and also print the status in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to save the status of the response of requests.post() to a file  and also print it in terminal. i have a list of hostnames in file, so one exception is caught it comes out and doesn't continue the loop. How t achieve he intended action.

```
with open(file_input,'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    try:
  for x in content:
        url='https://url/a/b/c/{}'.format(x.strip())
        payload=('{{"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password":  str(Pass),"db-name": str(x.strip()),"service-name": "y","port": "y","connection-string": "y"}}')
        response = requests.post(url,json=payload,header=add_cookie)
        print(response.text)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        # Whoops it wasn't a 200
        print ("Error: " + str(e))
    # Must have been a 200 status code
    json_obj = response.json()
    print (json_obj)
    with open('response.txt',mode='wb') as localfile:
        localfile.write(response.text)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Put code inside the loop in a `try except` block. To write the response, open a file in write mode and feed data.

Comment: i am getting json decode error for json_obj = response.json() . or response.txt not defined. will the above edited loop work

Comment: please fix indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved a little bit easier:

```py
import requests

with open(file_input, "r") as f:
    file_urls = f.readlines()  # read all urls into a list

for url_suffix in file_urls:
    url = 'https://url/a/b/c/{}'.format(url_suffix.strip())
    payload = {  # your previous payload in not a JSON representation
        "ip-address": "x.x.x.x",
        "user-name": "john",
        "password":  str(Pass),
        "db-name": str(x.strip()),
        "service-name": "y",
        "port": "y",
        "connection-string": "y",
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, header=add_cookie)

    if response.ok:
        print("JSON received:")
        print(response.json())  # NOTE: verify that response is a JSON
        with open('response.txt', 'a') as localfile:  # NOTE: append mode!
            localfile.write(response.text)
    else:  # status code 4XX/5XX
        print("Error getting url", url, r.status_code, r.text)
```

Note that you [should pass](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) `dict` to `json=` argument of `requests.post()`. Your `payload` is a strangely formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open(file_input,'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for x in content:
        url='https://url/a/b/c/{}'.format(x.strip())
        payload=('{{"ip-address": "x.x.x.x","user-name": "john","password":  str(Pass),"db-name": str(x.strip()),"service-name": "y","port": "y","connection-string": "y"}}')
        try:
            response = requests.post(url,json=payload,header=add_cookie)
            print(response.text)
            print(response.status_code)
        except Exception as err:
            print("Error: " + str(err))
            with open('errors.txt', mode='a') as f:
                f.write(str(err))
            continue
        json_obj = response.json()
        print(json_obj)
        with open('response.txt',mode='wb') as localfile:
            localfile.write(response.text)
```